# steps after including a webservice in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, soap, webservice-client

I added successfully a webreference to my asp.net vb web project.

But I don't know how to do my first search cause there is no documentation.

Could anybody give me some tips for the following webservice?

http://xml.lowcostgroup.com/soap/book.asmx

corresponding request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchRequest>
  <LoginDetails>
    <Login>login</Login>
    <Password>pass</Password>
    <AgentReference>IRELAND</AgentReference>
  </LoginDetails>
  <SearchDetails>
    <ArrivalDate>2012-08-11</ArrivalDate>
    <Duration>7</Duration>
    <RegionID>64</RegionID>
    <AirportCode>PMI</AirportCode>
    <PropertyID>0</PropertyID>
    <Resorts>
      <Resort>
        <ResortID>324</ResortID>
      </Resort>
      <Resort>
        <ResortID>343</ResortID>
      </Resort>
      <Resort>
        <ResortID>347</ResortID>
      </Resort>
    </Resorts>
    <MealBasisID>0</MealBasisID>
    <MinStarRating>0</MinStarRating>
    <RoomRequests>
      <RoomRequest>
        <Adults>2</Adults>
        <Children>1</Children>
        <Infants>0</Infants>
        <ChildAges>
            <ChildAge>
                <Age>5</Age>
            </ChildAge>
        </ChildAges>
      </RoomRequest>
    </RoomRequests>
  </SearchDetails>
</SearchRequest>
```

Comment: You have to use *proxy* class from `YourNameSpace..wbBookSoapClient` after adding `Service Reference`.

Comment: thx for your feedback, could you precise it a little more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added your web service, you had to enter a namespace in a textbox at the bottom of the window.  Within that namespace will be the service client you need to make calls to the service.

For instance, if you used "BookService" as your namespace your code would look something like this:

```
BookService.SearchRequest searchRequest = new BookService.SearchRequest();
// Fill out the search request

BookService.wbBookSoapClient client = new BookService.wbBookSoapClient();
BookService.SearchResponse response = client.Search(searchRequest);
```

Based on the code you posted in your comment below, you should update it to look like the following:

```
        ServiceReference1.PropertyDetailsRequest searchRequest = new ServiceReference1.PropertyDetailsRequest();
        ServiceReference1.LoginDetails loginDetails = new ServiceReference1.LoginDetails();

        loginDetails.Login = "";
        loginDetails.Password = "";
        loginDetails.AgentReference = "german";

        searchRequest.LoginDetails = loginDetails;
        searchRequest.PropertyID = 20; 

        ServiceReference1.wbBookSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.wbBookSoapClient();
        ServiceReference1.PropertyDetailsResponse response = client.PropertyDetails(searchRequest);
```

Comment: thanks again. according to your code what could be wrong here? ServiceReference1.PropertyDetailsRequest searchRequest = new ServiceReference1.PropertyDetailsRequest();
// Fill out the search request
searchRequest.LoginDetails.Login = "";
searchRequest.LoginDetails.Password = "";
searchRequest.LoginDetails.AgentReference = "german";
searchRequest.PropertyID = 20;

ServiceReference1.wbBookSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.wbBookSoapClient();
ServiceReference1.SearchResponse response = client.Search(searchRequest);

Comment: The reason you are having problems with the code that you posted is because your search request is of type "PropertyDetailsRequest" and the method "client.Search()" is expecting a request of type "SearchRequest".  I will update my answer with some corrections to the code you posted.

Comment: thx, we are coming closer to the solution. Still there is an error. Filling out the search request is something wrong. i have inserted the right login, pass

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with this service, so it will be difficult to troubleshoot remotely.  What is the error?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException at searchRequest.LoginDetails.Login = "asdf";

Comment: The "LoginDetails" property of the "PropertyDetailsRequest" object was null.  See updated code in my answer above.

Comment: after deleting an endpoint adress in web.config it worked... thank you very much, this was a fine starting point for me